# Vue CLI creates empty project

Tags: vue.js, vue-cli, vue-cli-3

I installed the Vue CLI globally and tried to create a new project

- my package manager is npm
- my first git message is "init"
- I add Babel, Router, Vuex, Linter, Unit Testing and config files manually
- I lint on save with Prettier
- My unit testing solution is Jest

This is what I get:

[image]

It only installs the node modules, nothing else..
I tried to reinstall the cli but it didn't help. Within the Vue ui admin panel each tab is completely empty because the project seems to be corrupted

(the language is german)

[image]

What might be wrong?

Comment: What version of Node and npm?

Comment: fpr npm I have 6.9.0 and for node I have 11.11.0